# C# - Namespace wide instance of class object

Tags: c#, static, global

I have to read a ini config file in my programm (please no comment's on XML etc. - cannot change that it is a ini) and have a class `iniParser` that allows me stuff like `iniParser.getKey("abc")` and so on. I need to access this object in multiple classes in my namespace.

I tried

```
public static class ConfigIni
{
    iniParser configFileIni = new iniParser("config.ini");
}
```

but this yield `cannot declare instance members in a static class`.
So I'm looking for another way to make the instance of my `iniParser` accesible througout the namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the instance static:

```
public static class ConfigIni
{
    static iniParser configFileIni = new iniParser("config.ini");
}
```

Comment: Well, this was easy. Thanks!